# Register custom filter in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

My filter is not being registered and not sure where it's getting tripped up.

In test/templatetags

```
__init__.py
test_tags.py
```

test_tags.py includes

```
from django import template

register.filter('intcomma', intcomma)

def intcomma(value):
    return value + 1
```

test/templates includes pdf_test.html with the following contents

```
{% load test_tags %} 
<ul>
    <li>{{ value |intcomma |floatformat:"0"</li>
</ul>
```

float format works fine but no luck on intcomma

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, you [haven't defined `register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout):

> To be a valid tag library, the module must contain a module-level
>   variable named register that is a template.Library instance, in which
>   all the tags and filters are registered.

Also, I usually decorate the function with [`register.filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def intcomma(value):
    return value + 1
```

Comment: That's not my issue, you can use both methods as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters)

Comment: @user2954587 yup, but still, you didn't have `register` defined.

Comment: Understood, but still not working. Any other ideas or ways to test what's going on?

Comment: no errors. I'm finding it tough to debug as it seems it's failing 'silently' or it's just not even getting called

Comment: @user2954587 ok, what if you omit `|floatformat:"0"` and try it with only `intcomma` filter applied?

Comment: @user2954587 also, I suspect there could be another reason. There is a built-in [`intcomma`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) filter from `django.contrib.humanize`. Try renaming your filter to smth different.

Comment: tried that and no luck. I've been restarting the server too and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: extremely stupid error on my part with collectstatic. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

import register from django.template.defaulttags

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
```

*views.py*

```
        from django.template.defaulttags import register
    
    @register.filter
    def intcomma(value):
        return value + 1
..........................other code.................................
```

[image]

*list.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    
      <ul>
        <li><h1>{{ 2.568|intcomma|floatformat:"0" }}</h1></li>
      </ul>
    
    {% endblock content %}
```

[image]

Output like this:-

[image]