# Why integers doesn't work within Django using {% with %}

Tags: django, variables, integer

I'm working with an HTML file within my Django web app.

```
{% with var1=1 %}
Indexig with variables: {{ticker.var1}}
{% endwith %}
</br>
Indexig with numbers: {{ticker.1}}
```

But then I get only this:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a custom template tag, see the documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
@register.filter
def index(indexable, i):
    return indexable[i]
```

Then use it in your template like so:

```
{{ ticker|index:var1 }}
```

Comment: 1. Wow, that was veeeeery helpful, thanks a loooot!
2. For people asking where the first part should be writing, do it within your views.py file, see how do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090735/register-custom-filter-in-django